# FEATURE_C12 e2fsck: Get a newer version of e2fsck!

Tags: upgrade, downgrade, backport

during running

```
e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0
```

i obtained:

```
has unsupported feature(s): FEATURE_C12
e2fsck: Get a newer version of e2fsck!
```

my os is Ubuntu 22.04, while the partition was created in (somewhere) 23.04.
How do i run fsck against upgraded version of e2fsprogs or how do i downdrade partition (both solutions are ok for me)?

Answer (score 4):

You can turn off this. You need Ubuntu 23.04 (or some other Linux system with appropriate versions), and the partition has to be unmounted, so booting from a live media may be good idea.

Simply run

```
tune2fs -O ^orphan_file /dev/device
```

After that your version of `e2fsck` should eat the device just fine.

Upgrading e2fsck is not something I would suggest. Bringing in new versions of core utils tends to come back and bite you later.